# Can't link against opengl anymore

Tags: 11.10, gcc, opengl, compiler

After updating to 11.10 I can't link code against libgl/glut. freeglut3-dev etc. are installed and it looks like they can be found too. I'm really not sure what's going on.

Makefile

```
gltest: gltest.cc
    gcc -Wall -lglut -lGLU -lGL gltest.cc -o gltest
```

gltest.cc

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH |     GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
  //glutInitWindowSizendowSize(320,320);
  glutCreateWindow("test");

  return 1;
}
```

Output

```
jonas@fortress:~/dev/checkouts/test$ make
gcc -Wall -lglut -lGLU -lGL gltest.cc -o gltest
/tmp/cct1HevY.o: In function `main':
gltest.cc:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `glutInit'
gltest.cc:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
gltest.cc:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
gltest.cc:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [gltest] Error 1
```

When linking with --verbose

```
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libglut.so succeeded
```

And then when checking the symbols in that file

```
$ readelf -Ws /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libglut.so|grep glutInit
   278: 000000000001dfc0  1581 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 glutInit
```

I'm very confused now.

Comment: It works when I put the -lGLU -lGL -lglut to the end of the gcc call. I'm still quite sure that this worked in the past.

Comment: Jonas: I've encountered the exact same problem, even after having triple-checked that I have all the necessary developer packages. This fix worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It works when I put the -lGLU -lGL -lglut to the end of the gcc call. I'm still quite sure that this worked in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Makefile` does not work anymore because of a [toolchain transition](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ToolchainTransition) (the transition was planned for natty but the change which causes your problem was made in oneiric). The linker flag `--as-needed` is activated by default in Ubuntu 11.10. This causes the problem you observed. The solution is exactly what you described in your answer.

> The `--as-needed` option makes the linker sensitive to the ordering of
>   libraries on the command-line. You may need to move some libraries later in
>   the command-line, so they come after other libraries or files that require
>   symbols from them.